# Can an escrow company require you to use a specific notary?

Tags: california, real-estate

I have an escrow company that's telling me I can only use one of their "approved" notaries. Can't I legally use any state recognized notary?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Isn't this question legitimate? SE is weird sometimes...

Comment: Interesting question. I don't know the answer. And the answer is in the weeds of CA specific legislation.

Comment: The answers should be yes, and yes.  And if your escrow company doesn't like the second yes, it is also legal to use another escrow company.  (you are only bound to their terms if you agree to them...)